# Assistance creating a table with different amount of columns on rows

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to create a table in LaTeX, which has a different number of columns on some rows. This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
           Title1             Title2
Row1   1    2     3       1     2    3

Row2

Row3
```

The only tables I have created previously have the same amount of columns on each row, this one needs three columns on the top row and then 7 on the next three rows, just not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} %say
 &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Title1}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Title2}\\
Row1 & 1&2&3&1&2&3\\
%and so on
\end{tabular}
```

Version with lines:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|} %say
\hline
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Title1}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Title2}\\
\hline
Row1 & 1&2&3&1&2&3\\
%and so on
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: How can I place grids around every item using this approach?

Comment: @user28462 The second version has got some lines.

Comment: @user28462 Don't use vertical rules in your tables. Their quality will instantly improve.

Comment: This will only supply vertical lines and not horizontal lines

Comment: @user28462 Vertical lines are from `|`, horizontal lines --- from `\hline`. If you need horizontal lines underlining only specific columns, you have `\cline{col_begin-col_end}`, e.g. `\cline{2-4}`.